# Mount externally accessible NFS/FTP folder in OpenShift (Kubernetes) container

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, openshift, docker-swarm

I'm currently in a project that is using DockerSwarm, and we would like to migrate to OpenShift.

It is a desktop application that watches a pre-specified folder for changes (file creation, rename... etc.).

This folder (NFS share folder) is accessible from outside of the Swarm container so that the user can place files inside and the application detects the file and does some computations on it.

The folder is mounted this way in Swarm stack.yml:

```
volumes:
      - "<folder path accessible by user (real location)> :<path where said folder is mounted inside container>"
```

We are planning to migrate to OpenShift.
Is there a way to keep the same functionality? keeping in mind being able to use the Java WatchService on the folder to detect file changes?

Comment: You can mount NFS as persistent volume and it will accessible inside your pod as a regular FS. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/storage/persistent_storage/persistent-storage-nfs.html

Comment: This way the user can modify the content of that folder and it will reflect to the pod immediately?

Comment: Mounting NFS as persistent volume is the same as mounting the NFS on a server. So if you modify the content of the folder on NFS. It immediately reflect the folder Pod mounts.